# In My lenovo IdeaPad installed ubundu18.04.now wifi not working.rtl8111 is my driver.can you help how to rectify.am just ubundu user only.splease help

Tags: drivers, lenovo

In My lenovo IdeaPad installed ubundu18.04.now wifi not working.rtl8111 is my driver.can you help how to rectify.am just ubundu user only.splease help
In My lenovo IdeaPad installed ubundu18.04.now wifi not working.rtl8111 is my driver.can you help how to rectify.am just ubundu user only.splease help

Comment: Since Ubuntu 18.04LTS (Bionic Beaver) became unsupported in April, 2023, Ubuntu 18.04  has passed its End-Of-Life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.  Please upgrade to a supported release. See https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/